# Kindle Fire HD MyClippings.txt missing

Tags: kindle, kindle-fire

I'm trying to extract all the highlights I have on my Kindle Fire HD - all of the books are non-Amazon (i.e. downloaded and then imported onto the device using Calibre).

When I open any of the books on the device, I can see all the relevant highlights, however the MyClippings.txt file (which presumably they should be stored in) is nowhere to be found on the device's storage - I've tried to look it up using the ES Explorer (enabled hidden files too).

What am I missing here? Clearly the highlights are there as I can load them all up when reading a book, but how is it possible MyClippings.txt doesn't exist on the device? Or is there some peculiarity with the Fire HD model where highlights are actually stored differently in some other files?